# Did anyone manage to import an Inkscape saved SVG into Gliffy?

Tags: svg, inkscape

Drag and drop does not work for me. The image is just a black box then. Tried with Internet Explorer and Firefox.

Comment: Try to save the file as "plain svg" with inkscape first.

Comment: Have you tried saving in different formats? Apart from the three SVG (plain, optimised, Inkscape), OpenDocument drawing (ODG) and HTML5 canvas (HTML) look promising.